# c#: Convert hex to GUID

Tags: c#, guid

Is there any way in C# to convert HEX to GUID?

Example:

I want to create a GUID with value equal to
0xa145ce546fe5bbcf1745491b50a4233d19b8223c0a743cad6847142df8b63821640beeabe82824b7d2bf507cb487

Comment: an example input would be good. "HEX" could mean a whole lot of things. Is it HEX in the proper GUID string form? Or is it just a series of HEX without the "-" separator?

Comment: A GUID is a 128-bit value. Your example are waaaaaaay more bits. There is no GUID equivalent to that example.

Answer (score 4):

If you know it's a valid GUID in one of these formats:

```
dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd 
dddddddd-dddd-dddd-dddd-dddddddddddd 
{dddddddd-dddd-dddd-dddd-dddddddddddd} 
(dddddddd-dddd-dddd-dddd-dddddddddddd) 
{0xdddddddd, 0xdddd, 0xdddd,{0xdd,0xdd,0xdd,0xdd,0xdd,0xdd,0xdd,0xdd}}
```

Then `new Guid(hexstring)`.

If you don't know for sure then with .NET4.0 you can use:

```
Guid g = default(Guid);
bool success = Guid.TryParse(hexstring, out g);
```

Otherwise you'll have to wrap the first in a try block, or check the format yourself first (e.g. with a Regex).

Edit:

Your edited question can't be done, you can't fit a quart into a pint-glass. There's enough bits of information in that for nearly 3 Guids.

Answer (score 3):

The [Guid(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ff78dc.aspx) constructor can parse string with GUIDs in several formats, e.g.:

```
string hex = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");

// hex == "ca761232ed4211cebacd00aa0057b223"

Guid guid = new Guid(hex);
```

See also: [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.parse.aspx), [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.parseexact.aspx), [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse.aspx), [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparseexact.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There are several constructors for [Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) that you could use as well as [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.parse.aspx) and [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.parseexact.aspx) if you have a hex string.

**EDIT:**  Given your edit, you could use a [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268207.aspx) but without knowing *why* you want a Guid, it's hard to give a better answer.

```
//untested
var bytes = new byte[] {Oxa,1,4,5,Oxc,Oxe,5,4,6,Oxf,Oxe,5,Oxb,Oxb,Oxc,Oxf,1,7,4,5,4,9,1,Oxb,5,0,Oxa,4,2,3,3,Oxd,1,9,Oxb,8,2,2,3,Oxc,0,Oxa,7,4,3,Oxc,Oxa,Oxd,6,8,4,7,14,2,Oxd,Oxf,8,Oxb,6,3,8,2,1,6,4,0,Oxb,Oxe,Oxe,Oxa,Oxb,Oxe,8,2,8,2,4,Oxb,7,Oxd,2,Oxb,Oxf,5,0,7,Oxc,Oxb,4,8,7};
var bigInteger = new BigInteger(bytes);
```

Comment: There is also an alternative [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the following should do the trick:

```
Guid g = new Guid(str); // Where str is the hex string
```

Of course you will need a try catch block around it in case str isn't well formed.